# DynamoDB Query throwing exception "The query can return at most one row and cannot be restarted"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm seeing occurrences of this in my application log for some DynamoDB queries.  I can't find any reference to this error message via googling.

Can anyone provide insight into the cause of this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: are you making parallel requests by any chance? I had the same issue but removing / modifying the way I make parallel requests to Dynamo seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

DynamoDB paginates the results from Query and Scan operations. Looks like there is a bug in your piece of code that is fetching the subsequent pages.

I noticed this error in my code and I found that in a query operation I was passing wrong ExclusiveStartKey. i.e. the values for the partition and sort keys mentioned in the KeyConditionExpression was different than the values mentioned in the ExclusiveStartKey.

Answer (score 1):

We were running into this issue when using [AppSync mapping templates to issue queries to DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query). AppSync encrypts/obfuscates the ExclusiveStartKey in a `nextToken` pagination token, making debugging this even more fun.

The error was occurring because we were re-using `nextToken`'s generated with one set of key criteria specified via `query.expression` with a different set of key criteria. This likely translates to different dynamodb `KeyConditionExpression` under the hood, similar to @Varun's answer.